# Put song on Video like in Instagram, Snapchat (In Flutter)

Tags: flutter

I am developing a flutter application and want to add song to videos that I upload like we put in Instagram or Snapchat. How can I achieve this feature.

Can we use Spotify or something like that to achieve that feature?.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are some decent video editor libraries for Flutter, that take advantage of the FFMPEG to view and edit the video content, like the [video_editor](https://pub.dev/packages/video_editor) package.

However, you cannot simply record audio from your device, since Android doesn't allow you to record audio from other apps unless they allow it, just from the microphone.

And Be aware that there are author rights associated with music. Using music without a license might take you to court.